# Wordpress about a tutorial

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know something about [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/innovative-uses-of-wordpress-post-types-and-taxonomies)

> In order to create custom post types, open your template’s
>   functions.php file in an editor, and
>   place the following function within
>   the file:

Where is this file function.php in wordpress 3.0.3

Comment: Have you tried searching the base directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must open the file `functions.php` that is in your template directory, in `/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name`.

If the file is not present, create it.

Answer (score 1):

It is /wp-content/themes/[name-of-theme]/functions.php

e.g if twentyten (default theme)

/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Custom post types and custom taxonomies should be added through a plugin, and not through a theme. It is the recommended way to add these.

Just a couple of reasons why you should add custom post types and taxonomies via a plugin

- custom post types and custom taxonomies add functionality to your site, and **not** your theme. They also do not add visual benefit to your theme
- custom post types and custom taxonomies should remain available across themes. If a theme is changed, these should still be available to the next theme activated

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hahahhahaha, this is a joke. If this post gets removed.... That tutorial is wrong, CPT should **not** go into functions.php. It should be in a custom plugin